# Can we host drupal application on AppHarbor?

Tags: drupal, hosting, appharbor

I want to know if we can host Drupal application on AppHarbor ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at AppHarbour it's a service for hosting .net applications and as Drupal is written in PHP out of the box you can't.

Although you could try using a php compiler for .net http://phalanger.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress can be [made to work on AppHarbor](https://github.com/appharbor/Wordpress) and Drupal might be doable too with a bit a elbow grease.